# How to fix Invalid Time error

Tags: python

I have the following error:

```
[u"'00:56:93' value has the correct format (HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]]) but it is an invalid time."]
```

Is there a fix for this, for example, no item can be greater than 59?

So, the function would yield:

```
fix_time('00:56:93')
00:56:59
```

Comment: I'm not sure that would work. Would you want values above 59 to be truncated back to 59, or added to the next (hour, minute, second), so that `00:56:93` is actually `00:57:33`?

Comment: I am not aware of anything like this built into Python. However, I can't help wondering in what circumstances just fixing completely wrong timestamps willy-nilly would be a reasonable thing to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to carry overflow up:

```
import datetime

stamp = '00:56:93'
h, m, s = map(int, stamp.split(':'))
seconds = h*3600 + m*60 + s
new_stamp = str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=seconds))
# '0:57:33'
```

if you want to just limit values:

```
maxima = (23, 59, 59)
as_numbers = map(int, stamp.split(':'))
with_limits = zip(as_numbers, maxima)
limited = map(min, with_limits)
str(datetime.time(*limited))
# '00:56:59'
```

and if you are sure you always have exactly two digits, you don't even need to convert to ints:

```
maxima = ('23', '59', '59')
':'.join(map(min, stamp.split(':'), maxima))
# '00:56:59'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function --

```
def fix_time(value):
    if not value:
        return value
    if not re.match('\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}',value):
        return value

    hours, minutes, seconds = int(value.split(':')[0]), int(value.split(':')[1]), int(value.split(':')[2])
    total_seconds = (seconds) + (minutes * 60) + (hours * 60 * 60)
    formatted_seconds = total_seconds % 60
    formatted_minutes = (total_seconds / 60) % 60
    formatted_hours = total_seconds / 3600
    value = '%.2d:%.2d:%.2d' % (formatted_hours, formatted_minutes, formatted_seconds)
    return value
```